# Error importing module _md5, and relevant RPM

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script that used to run, although since moving servers at work it now throws up a strange error:

```
>>> import _md5
    ImportError: No module named _md5
```

The general setup is all correct, as is my python path and seemingly everything else. I was told that I need to install the relevant RPM for this to work, but have no idea what this might be - could anyone please point me in the right direction?

These machines have a setup that prohibits me using `yum`, so I need to make a request to those maintaining the system about which RPM I want installed.

Comment: What version of Python you have on the problematic server? As far as I can tell md5 module was standard for a while and then it was deprecated as of Python 2.5 in favor of `hashlib` module that implements several popular hash algos. It looks like the new server has some super old version of Python. See http://docs.python.org/library/md5  ... and ... http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Python 2.5.4, thanks I'll have a read through them, but this seems to suggest hashlib may be able to resolve this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on extra bit of information from the OP, they use Python 2.5+ on the new server.
Suggested remedy is to use standard `hashlib` module. Which provides MD5 hash implementation among other things.

Comment: `hashlib` also depends on `_md5`.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried "import hashlib" instead of "import md5", but still get the same problem with "import_md5  ImportError: No module named _md5".

Comment: This is baffling. The only two explanations I can think of are: 1) the Python installed on that server was explicitly compiled with MD5 off (I don't know if it's even possible), or 2) the Python installation is crippled somehow (e.g. when it searches `sys.path` in order to import `_md5`, no path is found that has _md5 library).

Answer (score 1):

Install `openssl-devel` and rebuild.

Or better yet, build your own Python package and deploy everywhere.